# How to handle mobile devices - A specific theme for mobile devices (not looking for the same responsive theme as on the desktop) and configuration

Tags: mobile

Magento 1.9.1.0

I *installed and configured* the **Porto Theme #14** and it works great on the desktop. Somehow, it changed the URL for mobile devices trying to access the site (when they type in www.mySITE.com - it redirects them to m.mySITE.com - but there is nothing there at m.mySITE.com). I tried to search the web and also the support pages of the Porto theme on how to configure the mobile page but there seems to be no information whatsoever.

What I think is happening across the board is - people are just installing "responsive themes" that are "mobile friendly". **I think that's just NOT good enough though!** Imagine you have 50 products on your desktop version - that is fine I think but then someone accessing the site on a tablet or a mobile phone with just mobile data connection - it takes forever to load! Also lines and lines of text at the top of the desktop version (where there is a plenty of space for that) is fine but NOT on the mobile. So what I think is - I need to get a **SPECIFIC mobile design**. I've spent hours and hours looking for one but was not really successful. I tried Shopgate and it was really awe-full (it took them almost a year to get the site up and even then - it wasn't working).

I have 4 questions for you smart people:

1. Can anyone recommend a good (tried) mobile design I can install and run on m.mySITE.com
2. How do I actually do it? Shall I setup another STORE FRONT and use the sub domain m. for the URL? Would it be the same as when I add another STORE/STORE front using a different domain?
3. Where shall I look for the redirect that's already in place since I didn't actually put it in? www.mySITE.com going into --> m.mySITE.com on mobile devices.
4. Could I possibly use another Porto design and just configure it and load it onto the m.mySITE.com domain/store?